# How pass a clicked button's value when submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML form with multiple buttons and a submit button. I'm trying to pass the value of the button that was clicked prior to clicking submit button. The main functionality of the program is to upload a csv file in the respective table which has the same name as the button, i.e the name of the table is the same as button value. So the passed value will be used in the mysql query in the proceeding php page.

I tried it using php post method like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_POST['buttonname'];
}
```

index.php

```
<form id="upload_csv" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<button type="button" id="button1" name = "button1" 
value="role">Role</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" name = "button1" 
value="report">Report</button>
<button type="button" id="button3" name = "button3">Brand</button>

  <!-- uploading the csv file here -->
 <input type="file" name="employee_file" style="margin-top:15px;" /> 

 <input type = "submit" value="submit" name="submit">
 </form>


<!-- ajax code to upload csv -->

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(){
  $('#upload_csv').on("submit", function(e){  
   e.preventDefault(); 

            $.ajax({  
                 url:"import.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:new FormData(this),  
                 contentType:false,         
                 cache:false,                
                 processData:false,          
                 success: function(data){  

                          alert("Data updated successfully");  

                 }  
            })  
       });
           });
   });

</script>
```

So first of all the the submit button should post only if one of the button is clicked before that. And if the button clicked and then submit button is clicked, the value of the clicked button is to be passed to the next page. For example, if the first button is clicked, then the value "role" should be passed.

Comment: You're gonna' need some AJAX.

Comment: Using buttons as radio elements? Style radio button's label to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax` and `jquery` for that i.e : `onclick` of button get value of it and then `onclick` of submit pass clicked button value to php page by using ajax .For example :

```js
//on click of button get value
$("button").on("click", function() {

  //getting  button click value
  var value = $(this).val();
  console.log(value);
  $("input[name='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(value);
    //calling ajax
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "yourphppage",
      data: {
        'value': value //<-passing value to php
      },
      success: function(response) {
        //display something 
        alert(response);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR) {

        alert("There was a problem");
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <button type="button" id="button1" name="button1" value="role">Role</button>
  <button type="button" id="button2" name="button1" value="report">Report</button>
  <button type="button" id="button3" name="button3" value="brand">Brand</button>

  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And then `get value` of button in php page like below :

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
echo $_POST['value'];
}
```

Updated 1:

---

Try like below , i have use [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to append key/values to `formData` . i.e :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    //getting  button click value
    var value = $(this).val();
     console.log(value);
    $('#upload_csv').on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     
      //creating object for form
      var formData = new FormData();
      //appenfing data for button value
      formData.append('values', value);
      //append file
      
      formData.append('files', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);



      $.ajax({
        url: "import.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {

          alert("Data updated successfully");

        }
      })
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload_csv" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <button type="button" id="button1" name="button1" value="role">Role</button>
  <button type="button" id="button2" name="button1" value="report">Report</button>
  <button type="button" id="button3" name="button3" value="brand">Brand</button>

  <!-- uploading the csv file here -->
  <input type="file" name="employee_file" style="margin-top:15px;" id="myFileInput" />

  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this.

Comment: Hi. It's not working. I already have another ajax code in the page on submit button. I'm not sure how to append this to that code.

Comment: Hi. It's not working. I changed the form method to GET, but I cannot see the button value in the URL.